# Finding partials given three different equations

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

So I'm trying to understand some of these physics concepts we've been going over in class. I'm supposed to find some partial's but I don't think I'm quite understanding the process/mathematics behind it.

Given I have:
$$m=pq \\
a\sin(p-p)=q \\
b\cos(q+q)=p 
$$
**What I've done so far (which I think is right)**
$$
\mathrm{d}q = a\cos(p-p)(\mathrm{d}p-\mathrm{d}p) \\
\mathrm{d}p= -b\sin(q+q)(\mathrm{d}q+\mathrm{d}q)
$$
I'm supposed to find $\left(\frac{\partial(p)}{\partial(q)}\right)_m$, $\left(\frac{\partial(p)}{\partial(q)}\right)_a$

I know the answers for these specific ones are :

$$
\left(\frac{\partial(p)}{\partial(q)}\right)_m=\frac {-p}{q} \\
\left(\frac{\partial(p)}{\partial(q)}\right)_a= \frac {1}{a\cos (p-1)}
$$

I'm just not sure on the math to get to those answers. I was wondering if someone could help me understand these so I can apply it to more examples I have to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you really mean $a\sin(p-p)$? That equation reduces to $0=q$ if so, which then also means that $b=p$..